# Reference an object through one of its parameters

Tags: ruby

Say you have a class with instance variables of classes Bar1, Bar2, Bar3. The Bar class definitions are arbitrary, and are just similar in name for the sake of example.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :test_value

  def initialize
    @test_value = "awesome"
    @bar1 = Bar1.new
    @bar2 = Bar2.new
    @bar3 = Bar3.new
  end
end
```

Where Bar1, Bar2, Bar3 are defined as

```
class Bar1
  def initialize
    @value = owner.test_value # 'owner' would refer the Foo instance that contains this Bar1
  end
end

class Bar2
  def initialize
    @value = owner.test_value
  end
end

class Bar3
  def initialize
    @value = owner.test_value
  end
end
```

I made up the owner value just for the sake of demonstration, is something like this even possible? This seems like kind of a stretch, and could probably be solved by just restructuring the code I have that demands this functionality, but I want to see if it's possible before I completely abandon it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :test_value

  def initialize
    @test_value = "awesome"
    @bar1 = Bar1.new(self)
    @bar2 = Bar2.new(self)
    @bar3 = Bar3.new(self)
  end
end

class Bar1
  def initialize owner
    @value = owner.test_value
  end
end

class Bar2
  def initialize owner
    @value = owner.test_value
  end
end

class Bar3
  def initialize owner
    @value = owner.test_value
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also just hold on to a reference to the owner if that's what you really wanted.    Just add the line `@owner = owner` in `initialize`.  There are no rules about which Ruby objects can hold reference to which other objects.  It's not like the objects form a tree or anything like that.

Comment: This works just fine, I failed to think of doing this after a long day of programming, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An object can't tell what its "owner" is because it could be assigned to a thousand different variables at once. The only approximation is if you explicitly set an instance variable when you create the object, e.g.:

```
def Foo
  attr_reader :test_value, :bar1

  def initialize
    @test_value = 'awesome'

    @bar1 = Bar1.new
    @bar1.owner = self  # you could also make Bar1#new take an argument which
  end                   # would be assigned to @owner
end

def Bar1
  attr_accessor :owner

  def initialize
    # ...
  end

  def value
    owner.test_value
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar1.value # => 'awesome'
```

Comment: Same concept as the above answer, thanks for the input though.